# OpenRowset vs Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, security

I know this type of question crops up frequently, but nothing I can find here or on other sites seems to give a valid justification for not using openrowset queries other than "everyone says it's bad, therefore it must be bad, even though they can't justify why".

We have a setup with a master server (let's call this ServerMaster) which has connections to a number of child servers (ServerChild1, ServerChild2 etc). These child servers also have read and write access via a linked server to ServerMaster. In our scenario there is no getting around this. For various reasons, there is general two way interaction between ServerMaster and ServerChildren. The databases on ServerChild boxes (potential 1000+ databases) have to write to ServerMaster. This access, via the linked server, uses a trusted connection, not a specific account.

We also have a windows service that processes a queue on ServerMaster. This service makes a connection using a specific account to run the proc that serves the queue. When a request hits this queue, the service calls another proc on ServerMaster to generate a number of scripts to execute against the databases on ServerChild. The proc, runs a number of queries against a defined set of tables to get the rows that it needs to build the scripts. This involves checking a set of tables on the databases on each ServerChild. These tables are all different but ultimately have a common base, namely an Item and Version. In some of the tables these columns exist. In others they exist but with different names (i.e. Part and Revision). In others still, they do not exist but can be tied back up the relationship structure (i.e. Parts table has Part, Revision and PartID (PK) and related to that is PartAspects which joins on PartID.

Because the data ties back into the primary sources which are defined in a table we have to join the base table, Parts, to a defined query that gives us the joins in a consistent manner and the keys for identification. So, to do this we have a column defined for each table that gives us this query.

So, our management table looks like this:

```
TableName: Parts
LockQuery: SELECT PartID As ItemID, Revision As Version, PartID FROM Parts

TableName: PartAspects
LockQuery: SELECT p.PartID As ItemID, p.Revision As Version, pa.AspectID FROM Parts p JOIN PartAspects pa ON p.PartID = pa.PartID
```

This means that when we run through each of the tables we are able to define a consistent structure to get to the right set of data across all the ServerChild boxes.

Because of the nature of the LockQuery we are executing this with OPENQUERY. This aspect of the query joins to temp tables generated in the proc as well as other physical tables on ServerMaster.

Now, in a temporary dev environment (unrelated to anything live) we have used a plain text password whilst we wait for our IT department to sort out some cross server issues. This, obviously, is not going to make it out of this isolated temporary environment, but it has raised the question from our DBAs as to why we are using the "insecure" method of Openquery. The DBAs do acknowledge that they do not know why it is "insecure" and cannot provide any supportable scenarios as to what makes it insecure, but as everyone on the internet says it is, then it must be. Of course, when our IT department sort out the cross server issues, we'll be making this connection via a trusted connection with a strictly limited single service account having permission on only the objects it needs.

The justifications that have been give so far are that this should be done via linked servers because "that's what Microsoft recommend". Well, as far as I can tell, that's not what MS recommend at all. MS previously enabled Ad Hoc queries on install, but stopped doing this from 2008. This wasn't because it was inherently bad, it was because it is common sense to switch off things you don't need, unless you need them. If an experienced developer/dba needs them, they can enable them.

The second argument is always, MS say "OPENDATASOURCE should be used only to reference OLE DB data sources that are accessed infrequently. For any data sources that will be accessed more than several times, define a linked server." which also seems to be translated by everyone as "don't use this, ever, unless it's a one off single query that you'll never run again." Infrequent is a very open term. My interpretation of this is that as our code is running a single select statement from a single proc, only when the service processes this queue, that is infrequent. It is not a regular process fired by multiple operators on a regular basis.

Now, this "could" be refactored to use replacement values in the query, and therefore forced to run the queries all against linked servers. This would require each aspect of the query being run on ServerMaster rather than the entire query being fired on the ServerChild resulting in a far less efficient process (considering this will run against 1000+ databases), not to mention that it would require a messy solution of using replacement strings to execute it against multiple databases on multiple ServerChildren.

Argument 3 is that this exposes a greater attack area than linked servers. To an extent, this is true. However, that attack area is only as big as the security allows. If a sysadmin account for a ServerChild is compromised an attacker could, use ServerMaster to perform nefarious actions on ServerChild. However, they could also do this directly on ServerChild without needing to have a set of compromised credentials for ServerMaster in the first place. This isn't an issue with AdHoc queries, this is an issue of compromised accounts. Similarly, if the account on ServerMaster is compromised, they only have the access that this account gives. If it doesn't have access to anything other than the necessary on ServerChild, the risk is no greater than it is through a linked server.

Finally, and this is the one that seems to freak everyone out, enabling this on ServerChild means that a hacker having compromised an account on ServerChild can connect to their own server from within the ServerChild and dump out everything they want. This again, may be true, if the security is configured so badly as to allow this. But, the reality of the situation is that these boxes all sit within our own environment. They are all behind a DMZ and none of them have access outside of the domain. They are, cocooned internally and so our "risk" here, is that an internal bad actor accesses data that they shouldn't. Now, when you consider that the data in this scenario is already present in all the ServerChild boxes and is not sensitive or even meaningful in any way out of context, the risk is (a) no greater than that exposed via linked servers, (b) a risk that could only be exposed by poorly configured security (allowing access to unnecessary objects), or (c) a risk that should be addressed by configuration of the DMZ not SQL Server.

This is an example of the query we run (obviously the code isn't dynamic here but the connection and query are when we execute it:

```
    UPDATE lc
    SET DefinedAspect = pa.SourceDataColumn
    FROM #LocalObjects lc
    JOIN OPENROWSET('ConnectionSettings', 'SELECT p.PartID As ItemID, p.Revision As Version, pa.AspectID FROM Parts p JOIN PartAspects pa ON p.PartID = pa.PartID') clk
    ON lc.ItemID = clk.ItemID
      AND lc.Version = clk.Version
    JOIN PartAspect pa
    ON clk.AspectID = pa.ASpectID
```

So, what I am looking for here is someone that can provide a genuine, and supportable reason why we should rip out the current code and redo it in the less efficient and less elegant way of linked servers.

Bear in mind, suggesting that we change the model and use replication for example is not on the table here. I am looking to prove that AdHoc queries are no more risky in this scenario than linked servers, and that if security is configured properly any concerns are present in both approaches and can be mitigated with proper security controls.

Please don't say "MS say X" because that doesn't give me a definitive answer as to why one approach is better than the other. I am looking to make a case and the current thinking is that if everyone says it's bad, it must be.

As you can probably tell, I am sceptical at best about that argument, but if someone can show me a tangible and supportable reason why it's bad I'll be more than happy to go along with it.

Comment: Opinion: in my understanding, underlying security wise connecting through `OPENROWSET` is no different then using Linked Servers. The issue is that using `OPENROWSET` bad actor can try to connect to any server they like. The reason it is disabled by default is part of the defence in depth strategy, i.e. if someone gains unauthorised access through less privileged account to one server they can't use it to gain access to all others. When `OPENROWSET` is enabled you need to be extra careful with how you setup your accounts.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Can you expand on how someone with access to a less privileged account can gain access to all others? For openqry to work they would need to have compromised permissions on Svr A & make a conn to Svr B using a valid set of creds for Server B. These would be either the same creds (& hopefully the same permissions) using trusted connection, in which case openqry would be pointless since the creds they have would allow them to connect to Svr B directly, or they would have to decrypt working creds from the conn string. Not trying to shoot you down, just want to clarify understanding.

Comment: The point I was trying to bring across: They could also try connecting to server Z (which is not part of "your group" of servers) and if your creds happen to be valid for server Z, then they got access to it. `OPENROWSET` also allows you to import files. Keep in mind that an attacker does not necessary need to know login credentials to gain access, it may be some application exploit that allows them to gain access as that user. Note: I do not know enough about security to talk about more in depth aspects of it. Just offering my 2 cents.

Comment: "If a sysadmin account for a ServerChild is compromised an attacker could, use ServerMaster to perform nefarious actions on ServerChild. However, they could also do this directly on ServerChild without needing to have a set of compromised credentials for ServerMaster in the first place." You are overlooking the fact that the attacker may not have any access to `ServerChild` *except* through `ServerMaster`. Can you contrive of scenarios where this is not relevant? Sure. Does this mean that `OPENROWSET` in general is just as secure as a limited, fixed set of linked servers? No.

Comment: Thanks for the input Jeroen. I appreciate that in some scenarios openrowset can expose a larger potential attack area, but I'm looking to make the case for our specific scenario. What do you mean by the attacker may not have access except through ServerMaster? Again, I'm no security expert (hence asking the questions), but if a sysadmin account for ServerChild is compromised, surely that account means they now do have access?

Comment: Even if an attacker has credentials for a sysadmin account for `ServerChild` (which could be either a local or a domain account) they may not have *network* access to `ServerChild`, being restricted to somehow leveraging this access from `ServerMaster`, which in turn means they're restricted to whatever permissions the linked server account mapping dictates. If they're transparently mapped as sysadmins there, then obviously they have full access, at least on the SQL level, but this is at least configurable (unlike with `OPENROWSET`).

Comment: Furthermore, suppose that a completely unrelated `ServerFinance` happens to be reachable from `ServerMaster` (and nowhere else), but should not generally be accessed at all. If the same accounts are sysadmin on `ServerMaster` and `ServerFinance` (obviously a bad idea in itself, but hey), then an attacker who compromises `SeverChild` that connects to `ServerMaster` cannot leverage this into an attack on `ServerFinance` if there is no linked server, but they can easily do so if they can use `OPENROWSET`. Not your scenario -- just to explain why `OPENROWSET` deserves to be more restricted.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Jeroen. Yes, indeed these are good points. I agree completely, OpenRowset is a more flexible option than a linked server, and that, given the right circumstances, this could expose a hole. It's not what we have, and so not a risk for my scenario, but point taken, it definitely is worth mentioning, thanks.